# OpenGL text rendering methods and trade-offs

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, fonts

**Background**

I work on the game [Bitfighter](http://bitfighter.org/).  We're still compatible with OpenGL 1.1 and compile for OSX, Windows, and Linux.

We use vector graphics for *everything*, including text rendering and manipulation.  We use a slightly-modified variation of 'FontStrokeRoman' from GLUT, which is just a bunch of static lines.  We like this as it seems to perform very well, easy to rotate/scale/manipulate.  We also allow for in-game chat so text is drawn on the fly.

**Problem**

We want to use more/different fonts.

We've found several other fonts we like, but they are all TTF-type fonts that are built as polygons (with curves, etc.) instead of strokes or spines.  This brings up a few problems:

- We'd have to use textures (which we've avoided so far in the game)
- They're not easily resizable/rotatable/etc.
- Performance is significantly less (theoretically?)

We've experimented with converting the TTF fonts to polygon point arrays and then triangulating the fill.  This however has been difficult to render nicely - pixel hinting/anti-aliasing seems difficult to do in this case.

We've even experimented with skeletonize-ing the polygon fonts using libraries like 'campskeleton', so we can output a vector-stroke font (with not much success that looks good).

**What should we do?**

I know this question is somewhat general.  We want to keep performance and text manipulation abilities but be able to use better fonts.  I am open to any suggestion in any direction.

Some solutions could be answers to the following:

- How do we properly anti-alias polygon-based text and still keep performance?
- Do textures *really* perform worse than static point arrays?  Maybe I have a faulty assumption
- Can textured fonts be resized/rotated in a fast manner?
- Something entirely different?

Comment: I might be interested in looking at this problem. Can you put some examples of: 1) one of your current fonts and how its encoding looks like, 2) one of the fonts you want to use, 3) optionally, examples of your failed experiments.

Comment: Our current font comes from GLUT.  Source:  http://code.google.com/p/bitfighter/source/browse/zap/FontStrokeRoman.h.  We want to use orbitron:  https://github.com/theleagueof/orbitron.  I don't have some of the experiments on me at the moment.  One of the other devs Watusimoto) has outputs of things on his computer

Comment: Textured quads are so, so much faster for rendering flat text in OpenGL. Use libfreetype2; it is easy, will produce high quality results and will have greater performance (with texture atlases) vs. untextured polygonal glyphs. It is not possible to draw quality anti-aliased or (lordy) pixel-hinted text the way you are doing.

Comment: Experiment 1: Poly fill with a stroke to provide some anti-aliasing  - http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/4224/screenshot8da.png (looks ok, but is a bit fat, doesn't work well at all resolutions)
Experiment 2: Poly fill with no stroke.  Notice the poor antialiasing - http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/7373/screenshot9ka.png (with Roman stroke font for comparison)
Experiment 3: Poly fill with stroke to provide anti-aliasing. http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/4549/screenshot10i.png

Comment: Sorry for the imperfect comment above... I added more details, but lost the ability to save my edits in mid-change... the comments interface is the thing I like least about SO!  The Roman font is from GLUT.

Comment: "*They're not easily resizable/rotatable/etc.*" How are textured quads not easily resizable or rotatable? "*Performance is significantly less (theoretically?)*" "Theoretically"? If you don't *know* what the performance characteristics are, don't guess. *Measure*.

Comment: It is hard to measure when I have been asking people for suggestions on what to implement next.  I have also stated that I may be under incorrect assumptions and am willing to change them.  I didn't have a full understanding of how to render text, which is why I posted my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some convincing (thanks Serge) and trying out several of the suggestions here (including FTGL that uses freetype), we have settled on:

[Font-Stash](https://github.com/akrinke/Font-Stash/) which uses [stb_truetype](http://nothings.org/)

This seemed perfect for our game.   Rendering performance was comparable to the vector-based stroke font we used - textured quads really are not that slow, once generated, and the caching from Font-Stash helps immensely.  Also, the use of stb_truetype allowed us to not require *another* dependency in the game across all platforms.

For what its worth, this solution was roughly an order of magnitude faster than using FTGL for true-type fonts, probably because of the caching.

Thanks for the suggestions and pointers.

**Update**

The Font-Stash link above was a fork of the [original here](https://github.com/memononen/fontstash/).  The original has since been updated, has added some of the features that the fork, and can allow different rendering back-ends.

Comment: It also has a lot less functionality than some other solutions, so it might not be for everyone.  But it is perfect for Bitfighter!

Comment: I'm absolutely amazed by Font-Stash! Exactly what I was looking for. After unbinding the shader program and array buffers, if works fine even in an OpenGL 4+ context.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no OpenGL expert, or graphical expert in general.
And, really, Raptor, I -hate- to be the guy that says this, because I know how you feel right now.

I really hate to say it, but honestly, I'd just give TTF fonts a shot, using their textures and polygons as they were intended.  I doubt that such a usage would truly be detrimental towards your performance these days.  It would likely be more valuable to save time to use them as is, rather than spending time to experiment around for some clever solution that more fits your desires.

I doubt that text drawing using polygons/textures would be detrimental, whatsoever, to you performance.  This especially applies for today's computers.  How many years back, technologically, do you intend on supporting with your application?  Or perhaps you wish to run it on the Raspberry PI as well?  Or other mobile platforms that do not have high graphical capabilities?  Support of any of these could, perhaps, invalidate my claims.

But, like I said, I really hate to be the guy that suggests you to trudge forward as is.  Because, I've been there, asking for performance advice (sometimes over even tinier things) and just groaning when someone says 'forget about it, the compiler will handle it' or 'computers are so advanced you shouldn't worry about it'.  I honestly hope that someone else comes in with experience, and a good answer for you.  However, if not, I just want let you know:  I cannot foresee the possibility that using TTF, as it was intended, would be detrimental whatsoever to your gameplay performance.

Comment: Don't worry about being 'that guy'..  I was expecting it :)

Comment: "It would likely be more valuable to save time to use them as is, rather than spending time to experiment around for some clever solution that more fits your desires."  Good advice, but waaaaaay too late!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try outline glyph decomposition using freetype [FT_Outline_Decompose](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-outline_processing.html#FT_Outline_Decompose)  ?
Freetype is the tool of choice for font rendering and glyph outlines extraction. Hinting is supported and rendering modes allows you to specify that you want antialiazing, hinting, monochrome targets etc.

Freetype also has a built in glyph/bitmaps cache mechanism which may be useful.

Note : [OGFLT](http://oglft.sourceforge.net/) seems to bridge the gap between freetype and opengl although I never has the chance to use it